# Math.pow() in java

Tags: java

My code works but only if you enter a number that is higher than the last. Enter 1000 you get the correct answer but enter 500 after and you get the same answer. Any idea what I am doing wrong?

```
while (number > 0) {
    while (nCubed < number) {
        n++;
        nCubed = (int) (Math.pow(n, 3));
    }

    System.out.println("Results: " + (n - 1) + "^3 < " + number);
    System.out.print("Enter a positive integer (input ends with 0): ");
    number = input.nextInt();
}
System.out.print("End of run");
```

Comment: Hint: Try debugging by adding `System.out.println("n is " + n);` after you increment it, and I think you will see what the problem is.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because there is no inherent issue here other than a lack of debugging.

Comment: @JeroenVannevel It fufills the criteria for a debugging question as per the help center though, so it's not off topic

Answer (score 2):

You have to reset the value of `nCubed` and `n` after each loop

```
while (number > 0) {
    n = 0;
    nCubed = 0;
    while (nCubed < number) {
        n++;
        nCubed = (int) (Math.pow(n, 3));
    }

    System.out.println("Results: " + (n - 1) + "^3 < " + number);
    System.out.print("Enter a positive integer (input ends with 0): ");
    number = input.nextInt();
}
System.out.print("End of run");
```

Comment: That was it Thank you very much Daniel for your help!